# Moving a file on Mirth connect from one folder to other with custom code

Tags: java, mirth

I need to know,How can i stop the processing of the channel for a particulate hl7 file if certain condition is not matched for that hl7 file in source transformer or destination and then how to move that file to desired folder from source transformer or destination .

Answer (score 0):

Not completely understanding what you intend to accomplish, I would say you could use a source transformer to set some flags that you can trigger on with two destinations.  The first destination would have a filter and only continue if the flag is set to "true" and the second destination would only continue if the condition is "false".

Source Transformer:
- Look at contents of data/file name/something about the data and set a flag "shouldContinue" to "true" or "false".

Destination Transformer #1 (Recipient of data if "shouldContinue" is "true"):
- Filter to check if "shouldContinue" == "true"
- Transformer to build output
- Destination setting to send data if it passes the filter.

Destination Transformer #2 (Recipient of data if "shouldContinue" is "false"):
- Filter to check if "shouldContinue" == "false"
- Transformer to build output
- Destination setting to send data if it passes the filter.

Does this help?  Or I am completely off the trail?

Frans

Comment: Thanks Frans for your quick comment.I think you didn't got what I was asking.My question is How we can stop the processing of a channel for a particular HL7 file(if we found some data missing there in HL7 file) and move that file to desired folder/destination.